# How to hide logic behind a class to improve readability of method and refactor class to follow SRP?

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring, single-responsibility-principle

I have an algorithm to create a version for an entity and then I save that version against below 2 entity:

1) Variant

2) Category

```
interface IEntityVersion
{
    string GetVersion();
}

public class EntityVersion : IEntityVersion
{
    public string GetVersion()
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public interface IVariant
{
    void Process(Variant model, string connectionString);
}

public abstract class BaseVariant : IVariant
{
    private readonly IEntityVersion _entityVersion = new EntityVersion();

    public void Process(Variant model, string connectionString)
    {
        try
        {
            Transform();
            string variantVersion = _entityVersion.GetVersion();
            using (var myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                using (var transaction = myConnection.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        VariantRepo.UpdateVariantVersion(
                          myConnection,
                          transaction, model.VariantId, variantVersion);

                        CategoryRepo.UpdateCategoryVariantMapping(
                                     myConnection,
                                     transaction, model.CategoryId, variantVersion);

                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                        DeleteStep1Data();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //log error
        }
    }

    protected abstract void DeleteStep1Data();
    protected abstract void Transform();
}

public class Variant
{
    public int VariantId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}

public class VariantRepo
{
    public static void UpdateVariantVersion(SqlConnection sqlConnection,
        SqlTransaction transaction, int variantId, string version)
    {
        //save logic here
    }
}

public class CategoryRepo
{
    public static void UpdateCategoryVariantMapping(SqlConnection sqlConnection,
        SqlTransaction transaction, int categoryId, string version)
    {
        //save logic here
    }
}
```

I have 2 derived types(`AggregateCalculator` and `AdditionCalculator`) each having their own implementation of `Transform` and `DeleteStep1Data` methods.

```
public class AggregateCalculator : BaseVariant
{
    protected override void DeleteStep1Data() // Is it violating SRP ?
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override void Transform()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class AdditionCalculator : BaseVariant
{
    protected override void DeleteStep1Data()// Is it violating SRP ?
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override void Transform()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I feel like the `Process` method is doing too much work and if it would be possible to hide version saving related logic behind the `EntityVersion` class so that the `Process` method looks simple.

`Step1` and `Step2` are in sync so that if there is an error in `Step2`, I call the `DeleteStep1Data` method to delete all the data saved in `Step1`.

Also I feel like my 2 derived classes `AggregateCalculator` and `AdditionCalculator` are handling more than 1 responsibility, i.e. running a transformation and also deleting the data stored during the transformation process, although I am not sure if this is true or not.

Is there a possibility to refactor above code to improve readability and handle SRP ?

Answer (score 5):

### Trying to understand your question

You have an entity... when the entity changes, you want to create a change-version for your entity. What is not clear to me is that why this change needs to be tracked against both variant and category?

Let's assume your entity is `car` and the categories for that entity are: `Toyota`, `BMW` and `Nissan`. Now your entity, let's say "Toyota Corona with id = 123" is changed. Why do you need to track the change against the category? Can't you just say that entity with id = 123 has changed?

### Violation of SRP

As I mentioned in the comment, since you have left out part of your logic, it's hard to understand if your code if violating SRP or not, but I can give you some general suggestions:

You have a class called `AggregateCalculator`, I assume the main responsibility of this class is to calculate aggregation which happens in `Transform()` method. Now you require to execute 2 steps inside `Transform()`. This is not necessarily a violation of SRP... because from a higher level, your aggregate calculator does one thing: calculate aggregation.

You can look for general signs of SRP violation:

1. According to [Nikola Malovic's 2nd law of IoC](https://vuscode.wordpress.com/2009/10/16/inversion-of-control-single-responsibility-principle-and-nikola-s-laws-of-dependency-injection/):

   > Any class having more than 3 dependencies should be questioned for SRP
   >   violation
2. If the size of your class is too big, then you need to question it for SRP violation.

### Violation of DRY

Both of your classes: `AggregateCalculator` and `AdditionCalculator` do their calculation in 2 steps, *step-1* and *step-2*... and you have a common method: `DeleteStep1Data()` in both classes to delete *step-1* if *step-2* fails... I assume the implementation of `DeleteStep1Data()` is different for each of these classes, but I feel it still contains duplicated code (not DRY). One may argue that this violates SRP too, because `AggregateCalculator` is responsible for both: Calculating Aggregation and "Mirroring a DB Transaction" (this is hard to tell without seeing your complete code).

It appears that both *step-1* and *step-2* are DB transactions, so a different approach would be to put both steps inside a single DB transaction... for example you can write a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AggregateCalculationSP
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION t1
        BEGIN TRY
            -- do step 1
            -- do step 2
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION t1
        END CATCH
    COMMIT TRANSATION t1
END
```

Now you can take out `DeleteStep1Data()` from your class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this versioning is bit different and bit complicated to explain in the question and category have a big role in version part hence it is needed.Also I cannot use SP so could you suggest alternate option instead of SP please ?

Comment: Its a bit hard to get good advice here, if you cannot explain the problem. Could you explain why using a SP is not an option?